# Can port of ShinyBuilder be configured to listen on different port/s

Tags: r, port, shiny, builder, shiny-server

Is it possible for ShinyBuilder to be configured to listen on different port/s? (by default on Linux it's listening on 4911).

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at the source. However you could define your own function:

```
runShinyBuilder <- function (...) {
  sb_path <- system.file(package = "ShinyBuilder")
  dir_mode <- as.numeric(as.character(file.info(paste0(sb_path, 
                                                       "/dashboards"))$mode))
  if (dir_mode < 755) 
    Sys.chmod(sbd_path, mode = "0755")
  shiny::runApp(sb_path, ...)
}
```

now calling

```
runShinyBuilder(port = 5678)
```

should open it on port 5678 for example.